# How is passwordless sudo achieved for the vagrant user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, vagrant

I am confused. This is `/etc/sudoers`:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers                                                                                                                                                                      
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

How is passwordless sudo achieved for the `vagrant` user?

The `vagrant` user is not even in the `sudo` group:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ id -a
uid=1000(vagrant) gid=1000(vagrant) groups=1000(vagrant)
```

And, as expected, adding other users to the `sudo` group asks me for a password:

```
user1@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for user1:
```

Comment: Did you look in `/etc/sudoers.d`? `#includedir` is not actually a comment... much to my disbelief!

Comment: WHAT? Are you sure? Not a comment because it has no space after it? Because there are other instances of it in the file. But anyway yes, I looked into it and it is empty.

Comment: Supply the content of “etc/sudoers.d” edit your question

Comment: Not a comment because `#include` and `#includedir` are directives. [ref](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#Including_other_files_from_within_sudoers)

Comment: I'd also like to know, because I have a feeling something similarly janky is going on in Raspbian...

Comment: @Ramhound it is empty, as said above

Comment: @Attie thanks for the link. That '#includedir' is not a comment is highly unexpected. But, as said, not related to the problem at hand.

Comment: I went digging... Raspbian has `/etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd` which contains `pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`, so nothing nasty there.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same doubt related to how the vagrant user was able to sudo without being in the "standard" places where we are acquainted to check on CentOS 7.

But on Debian's "bullseye64" box you have the following README at `/etc/sudoers.d/README`

As of Debian version 1.7.2p1-1, the default `/etc/sudoers` file created on installation of the package now includes the directive:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

This will cause sudo to read and parse any files in the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory that do not end in `~` or contain a `.` character.

Note that there must be at least one file in the sudoers.d directory (this one will do), and all files in this directory should be mode 0440.

Note also, that because sudoers contents can vary widely, no attempt is made to add this directive to existing sudoers files on upgrade.  Feel free to add the above directive to the end of your /etc/sudoers file to enable  this functionality for existing installations if you wish!

Finally, please note that using the `visudo` command is the recommended way to update sudoers content, since it protects against many failure modes. See the `man` page for `visudo` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the second part of brneor's answer is the key

> If this doesn't work, look for a 10-installer file **in /etc/sudoers.d**. This file may contain the above lines.

There's a vagrant file in /etc/sudoers.d/ that sets NOPASSWD. At least that's how it's set on the Debian10 box I'm using.

Comment: The OP says that ``/etc/sudoers.d`` is empty.